# Notice: Accessing static property PhpArrayAdapter::$valuesCache as non static, when try to get a collection of data using api platform

Tags: rest, symfony, api-platform.com, serialization

I'm using symfony and api pplatform, and I have a problem getting a collection of data using GET operation on user entity with Api Platform.

First it was working on a branch with other operations, after I did the merge into another branch that have JWT, it won't work, all the other operations {PUT, DELETE, and GET one user} works fine,
but if I try to get the all users data using **GET /api/users** it shows this error :

```
  Notice: Accessing static property Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpArrayAdapter::$valuesCache as non static
```

The full stack error :

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
"title": "An error occurred",
"detail": "Notice: Accessing static property Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpArrayAdapter::$valuesCache as non static",
"trace": [
    {
        "namespace": "",
        "short_class": "",
        "class": "",
        "type": "",
        "function": "",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/Accessor/DefaultAccessorStrategy.php",
        "line": 86,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter",
        "short_class": "PhpArrayAdapter",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpArrayAdapter",
        "type": "::",
        "function": "JMS\\Serializer\\Accessor\\{closure}",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/Accessor/DefaultAccessorStrategy.php",
        "line": 91,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\Accessor",
        "short_class": "DefaultAccessorStrategy",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\Accessor\\DefaultAccessorStrategy",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "getValue",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 236,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 136,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitProperty",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 243,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 136,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitProperty",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 243,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 136,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitProperty",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 243,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 93,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitArray",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 159,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 136,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitProperty",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 243,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 93,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitArray",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 159,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 136,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitProperty",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 243,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 136,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitProperty",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 243,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 136,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitProperty",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 243,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 136,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitProperty",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 243,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonSerializationVisitor.php",
        "line": 136,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\JsonSerializationVisitor",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visitProperty",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/GraphNavigator/SerializationGraphNavigator.php",
        "line": 243,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator",
        "short_class": "SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\GraphNavigator\\SerializationGraphNavigator",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "accept",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/Serializer.php",
        "line": 249,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "Serializer",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\Serializer",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "visit",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/jms/serializer/src/Serializer.php",
        "line": 162,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "JMS\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "Serializer",
        "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\Serializer",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "serialize",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/Serializer/JMSSerializerAdapter.php",
        "line": 60,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "FOS\\RestBundle\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "JMSSerializerAdapter",
        "class": "FOS\\RestBundle\\Serializer\\JMSSerializerAdapter",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "serialize",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/View/ViewHandler.php",
        "line": 468,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "FOS\\RestBundle\\View",
        "short_class": "ViewHandler",
        "class": "FOS\\RestBundle\\View\\ViewHandler",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "initResponse",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/View/ViewHandler.php",
        "line": 431,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "FOS\\RestBundle\\View",
        "short_class": "ViewHandler",
        "class": "FOS\\RestBundle\\View\\ViewHandler",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "createResponse",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/View/ViewHandler.php",
        "line": 315,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "FOS\\RestBundle\\View",
        "short_class": "ViewHandler",
        "class": "FOS\\RestBundle\\View\\ViewHandler",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "handle",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/EventListener/ViewResponseListener.php",
        "line": 139,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "FOS\\RestBundle\\EventListener",
        "short_class": "ViewResponseListener",
        "class": "FOS\\RestBundle\\EventListener\\ViewResponseListener",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "onKernelView",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php",
        "line": 126,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug",
        "short_class": "WrappedListener",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "__invoke",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php",
        "line": 264,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
        "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "doDispatch",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php",
        "line": 239,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
        "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "callListeners",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php",
        "line": 73,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
        "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "dispatch",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php",
        "line": 168,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug",
        "short_class": "TraceableEventDispatcher",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "dispatch",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
        "line": 163,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
        "short_class": "HttpKernel",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "handleRaw",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
        "line": 80,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
        "short_class": "HttpKernel",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "handle",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php",
        "line": 201,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
        "short_class": "Kernel",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "handle",
        "file": "/home/ahmed/Desktop/mondevisbe/public/index.php",
        "line": 25,
        "args": []
    }
]}
```

Knowing that I had conflicts after merge and I fixed them, is it something that I missed during that or some missing libraries ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I've just been stumbling upon the same symfony error:

1. Verify if the old version without your modifications/merge is working.
2. If 1) is YES, then it has something todo with your code

In my case I had a broken part in some of my doctrine ORM queries, which caused the error message.

Maybe this little tip helps you to fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I figured out that the new branch use fosRestBundle instead of Api platform, I'm not sure but I think it has something related to the existing of fosRest (like it has some conflicts between them since they use the same entity), so I just removed Api platform and use foRestBundle instead.